# Java executor.scheduleAtFixedRate adds up Delay

Tags: java, multithreading

I am experiencing some issues with the delay of the executor. My thread looks like this:

```
public void run() {
    logger.log("Starting " + tso.getName() + " for " + dataType);
    List<String[]> allRows = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String[] lastRow;
    LocalDateTime lastDate;;
    LocalDateTime lastQuarterHour;
    while (true) {
        try {
            // Make attempt to take CSV data for today. If there is no data wait several seconds and try again
            allRows = getCSVRows();
            if (allRows == null || allRows.isEmpty()) {
                logger.log("Sleeping thread due to empty list for TSO " + tso.getName() + " and data type " + dataType);
                Thread.sleep(MILISECONDS_TO_WAIT);
                continue;
            }
            lastRow = allRows.get(allRows.size() - 1);
            lastDate = convertStringToUTC(lastRow[0] + " " + lastRow[2]);
            lastQuarterHour = takeLastQuorterHourTime();

            // If CSV data is available take the last record if it is before last quarter hour wait SEVERAL seconds and try again
            if (lastDate.isBefore(lastQuarterHour)) {
                logger.log("Sleeping due to lack of information for the current quarter for TSO " + tso.getName() + " and data type " + dataType);
                Thread.sleep(MILISECONDS_TO_WAIT);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.log(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
  }
}
```

The first time i run my thread the delay is OK, but when the thread sleeps 2 or 3 times, the delay when the next thread cycle starts, is not what is defined in:

```
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(extractorThread, 0, WAIT_INTERVAL_MINUTES, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

So, when does the delay start, once the thread finishes its 2-3 sleeps and terminates or when the thread itself is started, no matter how long it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might have something to do with the fact that you're sleeping inside the Thread
`Thread.sleep(MILISECONDS_TO_WAIT);`

Try removing those and see if the problem still occurs

[EDIT] 
The answer to your question is that it will run every X amount of seconds and it counts from when the initial thread/next thread starts but if the thread is not available at the time of the scheduled execution (Because of the thread sleeping or for instance doing very heavy calculations) it will wait for it to become available.

Comment: Aye, I indeed think it has something to do with that, but the thread has to sleep :/

Comment: I think your thread pool is not setup to have enough threads to support the sleeping hence why you are seeing it slow down after a few iterations and not right at the start. @Tenorfly

Comment: "I think your thread pool is not setup to have enough threads to support the sleeping" what would that mean? @Jockie

Comment: When you create a ScheduledExecutorService you do something like this `ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);` and the value there will in some way define how many threads the pool has (Not exactly sure how it works) and if the pool don't have enough threads to start a new one it will have to wait until a thread is available @Tenorfly

Comment: @Tenorfly Pardon me. I was wrong, I went and tested this and it has nothing to do with the fact that you don't have enough threads in the executor. As you can see in the edit of my answer it will delay the whole execution until the thread is available (Simply because the scheduled executor only puts aside one thread for the execution of that runnable)

Comment: So would you suggest some kind of a fix to that?